# Remove Part of URL with Mod_Rewrite?

Tags: apache, wordpress, url, mod-rewrite

On my Blog, i have the following urls

```
http://localhost/listing-category/wordpress-themes/
```

My CMS (wordpress) enforces categories on custom post types, but i don't want them. I have tried disabling them, but there is no option. So, is there a way to use Mod_Rewrite to remove "listing-category/" from each url when it displays it.

To make it like so:

```
http://localhost/wordpress-themes/
```

Help here? How can i achieve this? What is the best way to do this? Is there is any bad effect of doing this hard coding?

Comment: mod_rewrite converts incoming URLs to alter them to other locations internally.  If you want them to appear different in the front end, you need to alter them yourself in the URLs going out, then use mod_rewrite to put them back perhaps when coming back in.

Comment: Also: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

Comment: This question belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-custom-post-type-archives/)?

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.